The supermodularity of probability of intersection
Definition for supermodular function:
Given a finite ground set $E$, we say a function $f:2^E\rightarrow\Re$ is supermodular if it satisfies following condition:
$$
   f(X)+f(Y)\leq f(X\cup Y)+f(X\cap Y).
$$
Given a finite sample space $E$, let $E=\{A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n\}$ be a collection of random events. Then, is $f(S)=\mathbb{P}\{\cap_{A_i\in S}A_i\}$ a supermodular function for $S\subseteq E$?

Given the inequality is satisfied at equality, the function is supermodular (and also submodular). This special case is called a modular function.
